# Is Artifact Evaluation anonymous?

Tags: conference, paper-submission

My paper has just been accepted. This is my first paper. I am going to perform Artifact Evaluation now. But is it anonymous at this stage?

If it is, then the path in the code that I open must be modified. Because many file paths have my name. My paper is this conference. It seems that there is no such introduction on his official website(https://hpca-conf.org/2022/artifact-evaluation/).

Thanks

Comment: For the particular conference you mention, Wetenschaap's answer if useful. As a more general question, the question cannot be answered by us, because each conference has their own policy. If something is not clear from the available information, you need to clarify it with the organizers.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Your last sentence is spot-on, but "each conference has their own policy" is a bit too narrow: the guidelines I posted are valid across a range of systems and machine learning conferences. See https://ctuning.org/ae/prior_ae.html

Answer (score 1):

The linked [Artifact Submission Guide](https://ctuning.org/ae/submission.html) specifies that the AE process is single-blind. So authors should not anonymize their submissions.

Additionally, "If you have questions or suggestions, do not hesitate to get in touch with the the AE chairs or the community using the Artifact Evaluation google group", so do doublecheck with them if you do not just want to take my word for it.